# Proof by Lagrange theorem?

Tags: calculus

Prove this (important) inequality using Lagrange's mean value theorem:
$$\frac{1}{a+1}< \ln \frac{1+a}{a}< \frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I had in mind to use the MVT on the interval (0,a), and then try to apply some magic.

Comment: I'd try on the interval $[a,a+1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a>0$ then the logarithm is differentiable on $[a,a+1]$, then by Lagrange's mean value theorem, there exist a $\xi$ such that $a<\xi<a+1$ and

$$\frac1\xi=\frac{\log(a+1)-\log a}{a+1-a}=\log\frac{1+a}a$$

The inequality $a<\xi<a+1$ can be rewritten as

$$\frac1{a+1}<\frac1\xi<\frac1{a}$$

Now substitute $\frac1\xi$ and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=ln(x)\\x\epsilon  [a,a+1]\\a>0$$now apply Lagrange's mean value theorem: $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)\\\frac{f(a+1)-f(a)}{a+1-a}=f'(c)\\\frac{ln(a+1)-ln(a)}{1}=\frac{1}{c}\\a<c<a+1\\\frac{1}{a+1}< \frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{a}\\\frac{1}{a+1}< \frac{ln(a+1)-ln(a)}{1}<\frac{1}{a}\\\frac{1}{a+1}<ln \frac{(a+1)}{(a)}<\frac{1}{a}$$